# Deploying multiple huggingface model through docker on EC2

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, huggingface-transformers, mlops

I have deployed a NER model using the docker container on EC2. The generated docker image occupied 3GB with all the dependencies. I have a few questions regarding deploying multiple ML models.

1. Do I need to create an image for each application and orchestrated it with Kubernetes?
2. If so, is there a way to have the global environment dependencies for all the applications. I think creating 2GB of docker images for each application is an inefficient approach.
3. What are the common practices followed in this kind of scenario?

Comment: How much of those "dependencies" are the model data?  Can you distribute the model data separately from the rest of the application, and inject it using a Docker bind mount?  (This is a little harder to manage if you do use Kubernetes – not at all required – but using an AWS EFS volume could help there.)

Comment: With PyTorch GPU version and its associates, it took 2GB.  How to distribute the model data separately?